# screen title not being showed when nested drawer in stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

What am trying to accomplish here , is having a Top `StackNavigator`, and nest the `DrawerNavigator` into it , by doing the following :

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  initial: createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
      },
    },
    Nutrition: {
      screen: Nutrition,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Nutrition',
      },
    },
  }, {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  }),
});
```

but all I see is an empty white header , that doesn't show anything

[image: how the header looks like]

any suggestions of what I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: i think you should try the other way around. wrap `StackNavigator` in `DrawerNavigator`.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [material theming documentation](https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#types-of-navigation) :

> Lateral navigation refers to moving between screens at the **same level
> of hierarchy**

Still refering to this doc, StackNavigator allow to navigate :

> between screens at consecutive levels of hierarchy

So I don't think you should use a drawer navigator inside a stack navigator.

It's more standard to implement one drawer navigator containing multiple stack navigators like this :

```
export default createDrawerNavigator({
    Stack1: {
      screen: stack1,
    },
    Stack2: {
      screen: stack2,
    },
});
```

This way, you can set the title of each page in the definition of the stack navigators and it's working well.

I created a little working example : https://snack.expo.io/SyfeqM6ZX